# Paging with Spring Data Graph/Neo4j

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-graph

Is it possible to fetch `Page` results when using Spring Data Graph (Neo4J) as the data store?

The `findAll(Pageable)` seems to be the only Pageable query availalble when using the `GraphRepository`. What I am looking for is `Pageable` APIs for other `findBy***()` like queries.

Perhaps, there may be a completely different (recommended) way to Page results using Spring Data Graph. Thoughts on that are welcome as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Data Neo4j (2.0 currently in SNAPSHOT but soon RC1) added Page support for the derived and annotated queries. The `findAll()` is inherited from CRUD-Repository.

We could add Page support for the default query methods. Could you raise a [JIRA issue](http://spring.neo4j.org/issues) for that?

Example for derived and `@Query` annotated Page methods.

```
interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {
   // derived method
   Page<User> findByTag(String tag, Pageable page);
   @Query("start user=node({0}) match user-[r:RATED]-product where r.stars > 3 return product order by r.stars desc")
   Page<Product> getRatedProducts(User user);
}
```

Just add cypher (or gremlin) as dependency to your application:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-cypher</artifactId>
   <version>${neo4j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the details, @Michael. I am good even if the derived methods work - but when I use them, I get an error - "Cypher is not available, please add it to your dependencies". Any ideas why? Meanwhile, I will open the JIRA issue.

Comment: adding the dependency fixed that error - thanks! But I am now having issues with querying for two properties = getByProperty1AndProperty2()

Comment: what issues? Please provide some more context.

Comment: To me the handling of paging with @Query annotated parameters is not really clear. Does the example mean that the method is only capable of returning a Page objects or is there also a way to pass a Pageable parameter to the method so I get only the page I want to?