# Spring data neo4j method findAllByQuery from Repository cannot pass pagination parameters

Tags: pagination, full-text-search, spring-data-neo4j

I'm trying to achieve fulltext query by using spring data neo4j repository method **findAllByQuery**, but i am not able to pass pagination parameters.

From [doc]: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#d0e2149

```
@NodeEntity
class Person {
    @Indexed(indexName = "people-search", type=FULLTEXT) String name;
}

GraphRepository<Person> graphRepository =
         template.repositoryFor(Person.class);

Person mark = graphRepository.findAllByQuery("people-search", "name", "ma*");
```

Comment: check below link::

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028701/paging-with-spring-data-graph-neo4j

this might help.

Comment: Hi @Purnendu, i check the link, but i don't see they got an answer there, do you mean by declaring `Page< Person > findAllByQuery(String key, Object query, Pageable page);` in my repository?

Comment: Anyone can help on this question?